# Getting "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" error

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message

[image]

I'm getting "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" Error, whenever I click on any question on Stack Overflow. It was started a year back but they didn't fix it yet.

Comment: You're going to want to provide more information here.  I've never had a problem with that to the degree you're mentioning. What network are you connected to?  What browser are you using?  Are you using any plugins?  Do you see anything coming across as blocked when you inspect your connection in the console?

Comment: I'm using latest version of Chrome and Mozilla Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 but results are same. And I'm not using any plugins.

Comment: Then if multiple browsers return the same, I would venture that the issue is with the network, not with the browsers/plugins used.

Comment: Other Stack Exchange sites are working fine. I don't think if it is due to network.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/22679960/appium-clear-a-field

Comment: Dont give the URL of the error give us the url to the question?

Comment: They all url have one thing in common "error?aapxerrorpath="

Comment: Works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679960/appium-clear-a-field

Comment: All questions end up giving the error

Comment: Its on your end not everyone elses.  Try a different device (mobile)?  Try a different connection (vpn?)  I just tried the question you were trying to get to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679960/appium-clear-a-field and it opens right away for me.

Comment: Maybe you have some greasemonkey script that forward any questions to error path ?

Comment: Yes I can access all the questions on other Stack Exchange sites, the problem only occurs in Stack overflow

Comment: Yes because it is not on Stack Overflow

Comment: I can access those questions once I logout from Stack overflow

Comment: @iNullPointer: This sounds like some form of script blocking is at work. Do you have extensions to block scripts active?

Comment: I am sure that the problem is not from my side. As if they are also saying "This is our fault."

Comment: @NicolBolas no, I don't have any extension to block scripts

Comment: Wild a** guess: have you possibly/accidentally create a new account on SO and got it merged? This is probably a bit too far-fetched, but how did you answer 12 questions on SO before, that is at least haven't been "a year back"?

Comment: Earlier everything was fine. It happened after answering 12 questions @Andrew

Comment: but I have this issue for all the questions on Stack Overflow. @rene

Comment: Hmm. I see exceptions in our logs when you try to hit that question. Looks like something in the ads code? I pinged a dev on that team to take a look.

Comment: username checks out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should be fixed now.

One of our internal services, [Providence](https://kevinmontrose.com/2015/01/27/providence-machine-learning-at-stack-exchange/), was returning `null` as a value in one of its collections (eg: `['foo', null, 'bar']`). Those values were then being used as lookups in a [`HashTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.item(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1), which throws a `ArgumentNullException` if the key used is `null`. I added a check inside the loop to handle that case.

Comment: Thanks @rossipedia, the problem is fixed now.